# Rails_admin- ckeditor config.js is not overwriting nor paperclip running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, paperclip, rails-admin

I integrated my application with [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), and I put the ckeditor in one of the forms, I followed all the steps of the [official documentation on github](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) but it is not accepting my config.js, I reduced the amount of options because it was not necessary to have all but It is showing the default (full). And also not uploading photos, I tried the paperclip. Anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how can I resolve it?
Im using rails 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted out. After putting the gems in the Gemfile, and installing, I generated the ckeditor model, as it is in the tutorial. To get it to pick up my settings, I put it in `initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
field: field,: ck_editor,: ckeditor => {: toolbar => 'mini'}
```

and also

```
field: field,: config_js ck_editor base_location + "page.js" end
```

I put it in `initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile + =% w (ckeditor / *)
```